# i can open php file in browser but android says file not found

Tags: php, android

I am new to programming so I apologize in advance if this is a silly mistake. I have a PHP file named "info.php" on a server that I can open in my browser with no problems by navigating to: 138.68.176.180/info.php. But when I try to send data to this file from android app it gives me this error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://138.68.176.180/info.php

my code is:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        String urlParams = params[0];
        String targetURL="http://138.68.176.180/info.php";

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            url = new URL(targetURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                    Integer.toString(urlParams.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParams);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            //Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } finally {

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong on the server side? or on the code side?

Thanks!

Comment: Please dont mention Android Studio which has nothing to do with it. You are talking about your Andtoid app instead. Please correct your post.

Comment: thank you @greenapps -i deleted the android studio tag

Comment: Change the subject too please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to retrieve data, in string line your data will be appended as a complete string as shown in browser

```
public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://138.68.176.180/info.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
```

Comment: thank you Arun, I will experiment more with using JSON instead

Comment: I still can't send data to the php file, I am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @fjvs0283 you just try to display the line in textview so that you can see the output

Comment: thanks again @Arun Mohan, but I cant vote just yet, I have no rep!

Comment: @fjvs0283 that's fine you just accept the answer  you have provision to accept answer